# Examples? Multiple model nested forms and processing, Rails3+Datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

I'm searching for examples, but have found little to go on because everything seems slanted toward ActiveRecord. I understand the basic concepts for what I've seen and I'm working on doing this with Datamapper (dm-accepts_nested_attributes to be more specific). More details can be found here: [nested forms for 2 models in rails using dm-accepts_nested_attributes and dm-is-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495052/nested-forms-for-2-models-in-rails-using-dm-accepts-nested-attributes-and-dm-is-t)

I have a two model form for a Post with some text and an Image, that is it. The models are associated with the Post having n number of images and an image belonging to a post.

I've been over a bunch of different searches and blog posts but there are no projects or examples I've found to look over and documentation is sparse. Also I'm a learner/beginner/somewhat dense. I'm asking here for two reasons: working through my current issue, and so future questioners have a place to look.

Working with multiple models in rails forms seems to be somewhat complex and not easily accomplished, or it is but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is some code I pulled out of a similar application (Rails 3 + DataMapper + dm-accepts_nested_attributes + Haml).  In my example, I have a medical practice that has many administrators_practices and has many administrators through administrators_practices.  Here's the relevant part of the model:

```
has n, :administrators_practices
has n, :administrators, :through => :administrators_practices
accepts_nested_attributes_for :administrators
```

Then, in my view, I have something like this:

```
%h1 Practice Setup
%ol
  = form_for @practice do |f|

    %li
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name

    = f.fields_for :administrators do |administrator_builder|

      %li
        = administrator_builder.label :name, "Administrators Name"
        = administrator_builder.text_field :name

      %li
        = administrator_builder.label :email
        = administrator_builder.text_field :email

      %li
        = administrator_builder.label :password
        = administrator_builder.password_field :password
```

That should work.  The trick is to use fields_for and create a new form builder.  Then, you can treat it basically like part of the main model.

If you get stuck, you can break the pieces apart.  When I was learning to put these kinds of things together, I would work first on the model, then try and create a nested model there.  Then, I would build my views, and run a debugger inside my controller to make sure I'm getting the right information inside the params object.  Sometimes I could play with the params enough to see what it was supposed to be, then go back and update my views to get the form built the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of the official guide answers your question:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms